Mismatch between Javascript part and native part of reanimated (3.16.1 vs 3.10.0)
Current behavior
Before changes, i've got a stack navigation working, however when trying to implement drawers instead of just stack, i've got a the following error :
 ERROR  ReanimatedError: [Reanimated] Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated (3.16.1 vs 3.10.0).
    See `https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#mismatch-between-javascript-part-and-native-part-of-reanimated` for more details., js engine: hermes

Platform

[x] Android
[ ] iOS
[ ] Web
[ ] Windows
[ ] MacOS

Packages

[ ] @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
[x] @react-navigation/drawer
[ ] @react-navigation/material-top-tabs
[x] @react-navigation/stack
[ ] @react-navigation/native-stack
[ ] react-native-tab-view

Environment

[x] I've removed the packages that I don't use




package
version




@react-navigation/native
^6.1.18


@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
not in use


@react-navigation/drawer
^6.7.2


@react-navigation/material-top-tabs
not in use


@react-navigation/stack
^6.4.1


@react-navigation/native-stack
not in use


react-native-safe-area-context
^4.14.0


react-native-screens
^3.35.0


react-native-gesture-handler
^2.20.2


react-native-reanimated
^3.16.1


react-native-tab-view
not in use


react-native-pager-view
not in use


react-native
0.74.5


expo
~51.0.28


node
v20.18.0


npm or yarn
10.8.2



Executing the app via running npx expo start --tunnel
Phone :

Redmi Note 11 Pro 5G
OS Version : 1.0.5.0 TKCEUOR
Android Version : 13 TKQ1.221114.001

Expected behavior
Just trying to get the drawers working following : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/
One workaround that i have is to downgrade some components by installing the latest expo and fixing dependencies :

npm i expo@latest
npx expo install --fix

However it's not ideal because it means that I don't have the latest versions of each packages.
Reproduction
Here is the smallest example that i can make : github.com/nicolas-goyon/reanimated_drawer_issue
Steps to reproduce :
- npm i
- npx start expo --tunnel
- scan the qr code with a phone with expo (preferably the closest to what i've described)
Relevent files and code
Menu.js
The file that cause issues is src/components/Menu.js with the following code :
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { Login, Notifications, PlaceCreation, Places, Profil, ProfilEdit,Register, Requests,Reservations,Reserve } from '../screens';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


export default function Menu() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Register">    
          <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />                  
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

When changing the react-navigation/drawer to a react-navigation/stack cause no issues.
Package.json
The package.json is also causing the issue mainly because of the packages versions.
{
  "name": "iwa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "start:tunnel": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "iwa": "file:",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1307.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.14.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.35.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Have you tried downgrading from 3.16.1 to 3.10.0?

Yes, as said in the expected behaviour i could downgrade however its not an ideal state. I'm willing to have all of the latests packages

Had the same problem, running:
npx expo start -c

Solved it for me.
Source:
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting/#mismatch-between-javascript-code-version-and-reanimated-babel-plugin-version

Solution:
Try resetting your Metro bundler cache with
yarn start --reset-cache,
npm start -- --reset-cache
or expo start -c
and run the app again.
